# Print the name of the calling function to the debug log

Tags: objective-c, debugging, stack-trace

Objective-C's runtime seems to be rather robust, so I was wondering if there's a way to log the name of the function that called the current function (for debugging purposes).

My situation is that a bunch of things assign to a property, and rather than set a breakpoint and examine the call stack each time, I'd like to just `NSLog` the name of the function that is setting the property, along with the new value.

So is it possible to get access to the call stack at runtime?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <execinfo.h>

void *addr[2];
int nframes = backtrace(addr, sizeof(addr)/sizeof(*addr));
if (nframes > 1) {
    char **syms = backtrace_symbols(addr, nframes);
    NSLog(@"%s: caller: %s", __func__, syms[1]);
    free(syms);
} else {
    NSLog(@"%s: *** Failed to generate backtrace.", __func__);
}
```

Comment: This works great if you replace `sizeof(addr)` with `sizeof(addr) / sizeof(void*)` (or just 2).  Thanks!

Comment: Fixed. Oh, and Foundation actually exposes this really simply via `-[NSThread callStackSymbols]`, which returns an array. You could use it as `NSArray *syms = [[NSThread currentThread] callStackSymbols]; if ([syms count] > 1) NSLog(@"caller: %@", [syms objectAtIndex:1U];`

Comment: last comment: `callStackSymbols` is a class method. You must use it as `[NSThread callStackSymbols]`

Comment: it's actually NSArray *syms = [NSThread callStackSymbols]; if ([syms count] > 1) NSLog(@"caller: %@", [syms objectAtIndex:1U]);

Comment: Yup, `NSThread` has a class method `+callStackSymbols`, and `NSException` has an instance method `-callStackSymbols`. You can make your `NSArray` accesses cleaner by using the new literal syntax, so `syms[1]` instead of `[syms objectAtIndex:1]`.

Comment: @JeremyW.Sherman, how can I call this piece of code? Can you explain in details?

Answer (score 33):

Great Question. Combining Jeremy's Answer above and what we always use for our debugging, you'll get a nice string like this:

```
NSArray *syms = [NSThread  callStackSymbols]; 
if ([syms count] > 1) { 
    NSLog(@"<%@ %p> %@ - caller: %@ ", [self class], self, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd),[syms objectAtIndex:1]);
} else {
     NSLog(@"<%@ %p> %@", [self class], self, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)); 
}
```

Comment: Yes, you need to call this in the respective function where you want to log the call.

Comment: I did as you said, but he didn't print all history of worked methods begin from project run.

Comment: That's not how it works. The method above just shows you the calling function of the function you are in at that point. So you have to add it to every method in your project if you want that!

Comment: Keep in mind you can always use breakpoint in Xcode pretty easily (click on a line number and it'll add the blue marker), from there you can view the call stack. Or, you can just do `NSLog(@"stack: %@", [NSThread  callStackSymbols]);` and that'll print out the call stack.

Answer (score 2):

There is no facility for getting the sender.  Or, at least, nothing centric to Objective-C.

There are a couple of alternatives, though.

First, you could use GDB commands.  Go to the GDB console and do something like:

```
comm 1
bt
po argName
cont
```

Alternatively, you could use dtrace.  This is hard.  Or you could use Instruments which makes dtrace somewhat easier.

Or you could use the backtrace() function.  See the backtrace man page (x-man-page://backtrace).

Answer (score 0):

There is a C macro called `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` that will return a C-String with the name of the current function.  If you would like to convert that to an NSString for easily printing to NSLog, you can create a macro with

```
#define NSSTRING_PRETTY_FUNCTION [NSString stringWithCString:__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]
```

I use it all the time in my projects.

Comment: You didn't read the question properly.  It's not the name of the current function that is needed, but the caller.