# Print name of the caller of the calling function

Tags: objective-c

There's a great answer to the question "Print the name of the calling function" here:

[Print the name of the calling function to the debug log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046833/print-the-name-of-the-calling-function-to-the-debug-log)

Is it possible to go one step further and find the caller of the caller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yap. Modifying the example you linked:

```
void *addr[3];
int nframes = backtrace(addr, sizeof(addr) / sizeof(*addr));
char **syms = backtrace_symbols(addr, nframes);
NSLog(@"%s: caller of caller: %s", __func__, syms[2]);
```

Comment: You can also get a symbolic name for the caller with `-[NSThread callStackSymbols]`.  How would you get the caller as an `id` though?

Comment: @iluvcapra The code I've shown here is symbolicated. What do you mean by "getting it as `id`"?

Comment: How would you get the calling object itself?  How would you get the `self` of the calling method?  (Assuming there is one.)  Let's say I didn't care what its name was, but I wanted to send the caller a message.

Comment: @iluvcapra I don't think you can do that.